# How do i find out what city and whatwas posted with code?

Tags: bitcoind

065e7ad1111963cacd4e2ca978ff57023b8297c123911ffbb8a61011d29d1849 how can I see where that was posted and time

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by where that was posted?

Comment: You seem to be asking how to find out where a transaction originated. The Bitcoin protocol doesn't gather that information.

Answer (score 2):

This is not information you can find in the blockchain and whatever information you do find is not considered terribly reliable.

That said, you can see from blockchain.info where this transaction originated:

https://blockchain.info/tx/065e7ad1111963cacd4e2ca978ff57023b8297c123911ffbb8a61011d29d1849

The IP address that relayed it was:

45.33.113.199

When you look up this IP address, you find that:

http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/45.33.113.199

It's originating from Dallas, TX on a Linode server. This may or may not be the actual server that originated the transaction as there may have been several hops before blockchain.info saw it. Also, a user can have a Linode account and be pretty much anywhere in the world, so this information is probably not all that useful.

That said, if you want to speculate on where this transaction originated, this is one publically available way to do so.